# Loop linq query n times by updating property name

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I have this query

```
var query = from v in this._venueRepository.Table
                        join s in this._storeRepository.Table on v.VenueID equals s.VenueID
                        join w in this._workstationRepository.Table on s.StoreID equals w.StoreID
                        join t in this._tillSummaryRepository.Table on w.WorkstationID equals t.TillOpID
                        group new { v.DiscItemName_1, t.DiscItem_1, t.QDiscItem_1 } by new { v.DiscItemName_1 } into g
                        select new { Discount = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(p => p.DiscItem_1), Qty = g.Sum(p => p.QDiscItem_1) };
```

I would like to execute this query (probably asynchronously) but each time I execute this query I would like to update the parameter "_1" -> "_2" -> "_3" etc for example

```
var query = from v in this._venueRepository.Table
                        join s in this._storeRepository.Table on v.VenueID equals s.VenueID
                        join w in this._workstationRepository.Table on s.StoreID equals w.StoreID
                        join t in this._tillSummaryRepository.Table on w.WorkstationID equals t.TillOpID
                        group new { v.DiscItemName_2, t.DiscItem_2, t.QDiscItem_2 } by new { v.DiscItemName_2 } into g
                        select new { Discount = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(p => p.DiscItem_2), Qty = g.Sum(p => p.QDiscItem_2) };
```

etc, etc Any ideas how I can do this? Perhaps reflection?

Comment: I think expression trees are what you are looking for.

Comment: I only do this as a comment as I am asking you to rethink your data: you have a really big Table/Data structure with lot's of "_1", "_2", ... - may I ask why you don't just add another "Id" or "Nr" Field/Property and just use this?

Comment: Sorry, Carsten Konig, I don't know what you mean by Nr Field/Property?

Comment: @CarstenKönig agreed, this is an awful database design and should have been killed at birth. You should normalize the table for `_n`. That would make your linq statment easier to manage AND when you need to extend `_n` you don't need to do anything in your code, nor your database.

Comment: This is an existing db design for a product which is over 30 years old. Can't be changed....

Comment: I think the best way for you would be to assemble the select-string yourself and use *old*-style sql-commands (yeah it sucks but so does the table ;)

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is of course reflection as you mention. A sample based on your example is below:

```
var t = ._venueRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault().GetType();

for(int iterationCount = 1; iterationCount < MAX_ITERATIONS ; iterationCount++)
{

PropertyInfo itemNameProperty = t.GetProperty(String.Format("DiscItemName_{0}", iterationCount));
PropertyInfo discItermProperty = t.GetProperty(String.Format("DiscItem_{0}", iterationCount));
//Repeat the above for all properties.

var query = from v in this._venueRepository.Table
                    join s in this._storeRepository.Table on v.VenueID equals s.VenueID
                    join w in this._workstationRepository.Table on s.StoreID equals w.StoreID
                    join t in this._tillSummaryRepository.Table on w.WorkstationID equals t.TillOpID
                            //Repeat the below for other properties
                    group new { itemNameProperty.GetValue(v), dicItemProperty.GetValue(v) , qDiscProperty.GetValue(v) } by new { itemNameProperty.GetValue(v) } into g
                    //Similarly do for the select new.
                    select new { Discount = g.Key, Amount = g.Sum(p => p.DiscItem_1), Qty = g.Sum(p => p.QDiscItem_1) };

//Other code here.
}
```

If you are using the Entity framework, the above query will not work. The reason this will not work is that the Entity Framework will try to translate your query to SQL, and will fail at the reflection parts. What you have to do is split your query in two. Do the filter and join in one step and retrieving it to a List and then using reflection to create the anonymous types in another query. You will be using more memory however for this operation and you are losing benefits from using Linq to Entity.

Comment: have you tried to do this using Linq2Ef or something similar (I did not but I think this might be a problem ...) anyway - isn't this almost the same as assembling the *select-string* directly?

Comment: This will NOT work with entity framework, no. Let me revise my answer.

Comment: Answer revised with a solution that will work with the entity framework.

Comment: @CarstenKönig To be honest, practically this is very close to constructing the select string by hand. I would choose one over the other depending on the situation. There is less reliance on strings this way, but it will be slower. Also constructing complex select queries by hand is something I generally advice against.

Comment: This is why I will only comment on this ;) (I hate magic strings .... with a passion) - but if the table is this malformed well...